# Google Play Games Achievements - Points Not Changing

Tags: android, google-play-games

Earlier, I made 5 achievements and published them along with my game, which is in alpha testing.

Now I am trying to modify the 5 achievements, and everything else updates successfully (name, description, icon, and list order), but the experience amount does NOT update, even though I've changed the given points amount too.

I updated the achievements around 5 hours ago. Could this be some kind of cache/update delay issue, or is there something I am missing here? Perhaps I need to actually republish the achievements, for the experience to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The achievements needed to be re-published for the experience count to update.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read official documentation above [Editing an achievement](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#editing_an_achievement)?

You have the steps  to **Undoing an edit**, **Deleting an achievement** and **Resetting an achievement**.

And you should be careful, if you are to publish your app, because *once an achievement is published, its initial state (hidden or revealed) and its type (incremental or standard) is fixed and cannot be changed*.

Comment: Yes, I've read it. It says: _"At this point, you will see the same form you used when first creating the achievement, and you can edit any of the fields as you wish."_ - with the exception of changing the **Initial State** or **Type** - which are disabled anyways. Since the **Points** is not disabled - I am assuming it can still be changed.

Comment: And if you try to re-sync your Google Play account?

Comment: I must admit that I am not quite sure what do you mean by re-syncing? Where can I do that? If you mean simply Settings -> Accounts -> Google Account... I tried that, but it didn't help.